# Why QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, qthread

My Code...

```
import sys                       
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *     
from PyQt5 import uic  
from PyQt5.QtCore import *            
import pyupbit
import datetime
from upbit1 import *
import multiprocessing as mp

from QThread1 import Thread1
from QThread2 import Thread2
from QThread3 import Thread3

form_class = uic.loadUiType("autotrading.ui")[0]            
with open("pyupbit.txt", "r") as f:
            key0 = f.readline().strip()
            key1 = f.readline().strip()
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S')            
upbit = pyupbit.Upbit(key0, key1)

class Login_Machine(QMainWindow, QWidget, form_class):       
    class_attribute = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                     
               
        super(Login_Machine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        form_class.__init__(self)                            
        self.setUI()                        
                         
        self.login_event_loop = QEventLoop()
        
        
        self.k = Login()
        self.key0.setText(key0)
        self.key1.setText(key1)
        
        self.btn.setText("AutoTrading Start")
        self.btn2.setText("Login")
        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.auto)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.login_slot)
        
        self.buying.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.buying.setDecimals(0)
        self.profit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.profit.setDecimals(1)
        self.stop_loss.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.stop_loss.setDecimals(1)
   
        self.buying.setValue(5500)
        self.profit.setValue(2.5)
        self.stop_loss.setValue(0.5)
        
    def setUI(self):
        self.setupUi(self)  
        
    def login_slot(self, errCode):
        balance = upbit.get_balance("USDT")
        if errCode == 0:
            
            self.log.append(f"{now} Login Success!")
            self.log.append(f"my balance: {balance}")        

        
            
            
        self.login_event_loop.exit() 
    
    def auto(self):
        
        a = Thread1(parent = self)
        b = Thread2(parent = self)
        c = Thread3(parent = self)
          
        
        if self.btn.text() == "AutoTrading Start":  
                
            a.start()
            b.start()
            c.start() 
                        
          
            self.btn.setText("AutoTrading Stop")
           
            
        elif self.btn.text() == "AutoTrading Stop":
            
            a.end()
            b.end()
            c.end()
            
            self.log.append("AutoTrading Stop")
            self.btn.setText(""AutoTrading Start"")
    
    
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    p = mp.Process(target = Login_Machine)   
    p.start()
    p.join()
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    CH = Login_Machine()
    CH.show()                        
    app.exec_()
```

When write this code, the error you saw in the title pops up and the window goes off.

I thought this was going to be fixed, but another problem arose.

How to use multiprocessing in QMainWindow?

If do this, the loop continues from the beginning, don't go to the end.

example, If it is from 1 to 100, proceed to 5, then go back to the beginning and start at 1.

Maybe it's because I'm stupid,'pool' and 'multithread' the result was the same.

If anyone can teach me, even one is fine, so please.

thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: now, QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running is fixed. but... multiprocessing or multithread can't. Help me!

Comment: Qt gui isn't made to be used across multiple processes or threads and you cannot use processes or threads with its gui, accept this fact. You can use multithreading or multiprocessing in an app running qt, you just need to separate it from anything gui-related. This isn't a problem with qt itself, all gui apps work that way.

Comment: may i know how to do it?... thank you!!

Comment: qt is qt designer, is it?

Comment: Qt is anything with the letter Q in it, Qthreads are there to support a specific type of message passing by signals, it isn't made to "make your application multithreaded" it's made to "simplify communication", if you don't know how does it simplify communication then you aren't experienced enough with threading to use it in a gui application and will 100% only write code that will crash.

Comment: Just write the threaded part to work without QT, then write your gui logic without using threads, then make some communication between then using signals, what i mean is there is no "modify this line and everything will work fine", you need to learn more about threading and communication between threads as well as QT before you start mixing both together, orelse every line you write will have a chance of crashing your application with a segmentation fault.